# Converting string to variable type python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a string to a varying data type at runtime in python. For example something like this:

```
a= "9" #This could be 9, '9', etc...
b= "6"
```

where a variable `c` holds the value of `b`, but of type `type(a)`.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: are you looking for a way to compare different types like `"5" == 5`?

Comment: No. Anis R answered this properly below. I am looking to convert the type of a variable to the type of another variable

Comment: The use the `type()` of that other variable.

Comment: But I don't know the type of the variable until runtime, which is why I was looking for the solution below.

Comment: @figbar What could it mean to convert a string or number into a `NoneType`?

Comment: That was in there by mistake, removed now.

Comment: This really only applies to integers, floats, strings, and booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, what you want is to create a variable `c` that has the same content as `b` but with the type of `a`. **Assuming the types are compatible and `a` is not `None`**, you could do something like:

```
c = type(a)(b)
```

Example:

```
a = "9"
b = 10
c = type(a)(b) # "10"
```

Comment: This works for strings, integers, and floats, but I think it breaks down outside of those types.

Comment: this is exactly why I included "Assuming the types are compatible".

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for, thank you. This applies to bool values as well.

Comment: Glad this helps. If this answered your question, please consider marking this post as answer.

Comment: Yes, I just have to wait ten minutes after it is posted

Comment: `a = None; b = 6; type(a)(b)` => `TypeError`.

Comment: @ekhumoro again, this is exactly why I mentioned "Assuming the types are compatible". I guess I'll edit to also mention "and a is not None", thanks

Comment: @AnisR The question originally specified that `a` could be `None`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Oops, you're right. Thanks for pointing out